# How to only return consecutive values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a modified a dataframe to only include the line if its over a certain value. Now in this new dataframe, I want to modify it further to only include the lines that are consecutive. For example, if this is the dataframe with the index and then Timestamp and Value headers:

```
                       Timestamp     Value
316 2022-03-01T16:28:50.4580078Z    36.000
344 2022-03-01T17:26:25.8170166Z    37.500
345 2022-03-01T17:26:45.8480072Z    41.000
346 2022-03-01T17:27:05.8800048Z    35.250
374 2022-03-01T18:23:10.9630126Z    36.000
387 2022-03-01T18:36:12.1380004Z    42.000
388 2022-03-01T18:36:32.1690063Z    37.000
391 2022-03-01T18:37:52.2950134Z    34.500
```

this should return a new dataframe with only 344,345,346,387,and 388 because these are the only lines that have a consecutive neighbor in the index

```
                       Timestamp     Value
344 2022-03-01T17:26:25.8170166Z    37.500
345 2022-03-01T17:26:45.8480072Z    41.000
346 2022-03-01T17:27:05.8800048Z    35.250
387 2022-03-01T18:36:12.1380004Z    42.000
388 2022-03-01T18:36:32.1690063Z    37.000
```

I have tried iterating and appending to a new list, using `df.iloc[i]` and `df.iloc[i-1]` and still cant seem to get it working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### based on the time

You can compute the successive time differences and compare them to a threshold (here 1 minute). Keep the rows for which the mask is True (or that of the row below):

```
thresh = '1min'

m = (pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
       .diff().lt(thresh)
    )

out = df[m|m.shift(-1)]
```

##### based on the index

Same logic but checking a successive difference of 1 in the index.

```
m = df.index.to_series().diff().eq(1)

out = df[m|m.shift(-1)]
```

Output:

```
                              Timestamp  Value
344 2022-03-01 17:26:25.817016600+00:00  37.50
345 2022-03-01 17:26:45.848007200+00:00  41.00
346 2022-03-01 17:27:05.880004800+00:00  35.25
387 2022-03-01 18:36:12.138000400+00:00  42.00
388 2022-03-01 18:36:32.169006300+00:00  37.00
```

Intermediates:

```
                              Timestamp  Value      m m.shift(-1)
316 2022-03-01 16:28:50.458007800+00:00  36.00  False       False
344 2022-03-01 17:26:25.817016600+00:00  37.50  False        True
345 2022-03-01 17:26:45.848007200+00:00  41.00   True        True
346 2022-03-01 17:27:05.880004800+00:00  35.25   True       False
374 2022-03-01 18:23:10.963012600+00:00  36.00  False       False
387 2022-03-01 18:36:12.138000400+00:00  42.00  False        True
388 2022-03-01 18:36:32.169006300+00:00  37.00   True       False
391 2022-03-01 18:37:52.295013400+00:00  34.50  False         NaN
```

Comment: Sorry, did not mention. The threshold of time will not always be one minute, in this case it is, but in other cases it could be 5 minutes or longer and still be consecutive. The time can be variable.

Comment: @Bash you can use any threshold you want. How do you define "consecutive"?

Comment: Consecutive would be if the index of the data point is directly after another one. For example line 344-345 are consecutive but 374-387 are not.

Comment: I see, then use the exact same logic but with the index. Let me update